# Vue 3 как использовать Datepicker

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

https://github.com/icehaunter/vue3-datepicker

Существует готовый компонент Datepicker, хочу его запустить и использовать на своей странице.
Не пойму как это сделать. У меня два подхода сейчас тестируется.

1. У меня обычная html страница и я подключил Vue таким образом:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

в гитхабе такой пример, но если я его добавлю, то ничего не получится

```
<template>
  <datepicker v-model="picked" />
</template>


<script>
import Datepicker from '../src/datepicker/Datepicker.vue'
components: {
  Datepicker
},
data(): {
  return {
    picked: new Date();
  }
}
</script>
```

2. У меня запущен сервер на node.js и если я просто папку с гитхаба src скопирую в свой приложение с заменой файлов, то у меня выдаст ошибку

   Failed to compile.

   ./src/App.vue
   Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

   C:\domains\vue\test\src\App.vue
   85:15  error  You should not use an arrow function to define a watcher  vue/no-arrow-functions-in-watch

   ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компонент который указан, подразумевает импортирование через npm и там же в репозитории сказано

> The component is packaged mainly for use with bundlers, if you require
> a browser build - post an issue.

То есть без сборщика этот компонент нельзя использовать

[CodesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/12vk1?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) - вот тут пример работы

**Процесс интеграции**

1. Создать проект

   `vue create my-project`
2. `npm i vue3-datepicker` (в cmd из папки если что)
3. Можешь и в App.vue либо создать свой компонент

```
import Datepicker from 'vue3-datepicker'
```

Если template нету

```
<template>
  <Datepicker v-model="date" />
</template>
```

Если template есть

```
<Datepicker v-model="date" />
```

```
data() {
    return {
      date: new Date(),
    };
  },
components: {
    Datepicker,
  },
```

Вот полный код

```
<script>
import Datepicker from "vue3-datepicker";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      date: new Date(),
    };
  },
  components: {
    Datepicker,
  },
  
};
</script>
```

И пользуйся докой
[Vue 3 на русском](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/installation.html)

Comment: Здорово! Подскажите пожалуйста порядок действий: 1) например создание нового проекта "vue create hello-vue"  2) затем установка компонента "npm i vue3-datepicker"   а дальше как их соединить?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё получилось, всё работает.